# Why am I getting an OSError: [Errno 2] trying to generate a public key?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to create a public key from a private key that I'm generating with ec2/boto as seen below:

```
key_pair = ec2.create_key_pair(name)
private_key = '{}.pem'.format(name)
```

`public_key = subprocess.check_output("ssh-keygen -y -f #{}".format(private_key))`

At first, I thought maybe it was a permissions issue so I'm changing the permissions as such:

```
os.chmod(private_key, 0o400)
```

However, I'm still getting an OSError [Errno 2] error. The error can be seen below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "infrastructure.py", line 425, in <module>
        main(arguments)   
    File "infrastructure.py", line 374, in main   
        key_pair_name=arguments['--keypair'])   
    File "infrastructure.py", line 387, in create
        key_pair_name, key_pair_fingerprint, key_pair_pem = create_key_pair(key_pair_name, region)   
    File "infrastructure.py",line 65, in create_key_pair
        raise e   
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please provide the **full error message**, not an unhelpful truncation.

Comment: see if you can run it from command line. ssh-keygen -y -f [private key]

Comment: @ppperry Unfortunately that is the whole error as I see it. I don't know why it's truncated like that.

Comment: What happens if you run the buggy command outside of the debugger?

Comment: @Muposat I can create it from the command line:

Comment: @ppperry so this is everything I see outside of the debugger: [info] -----> Validating CloudFormation template

  File "infrastructure.py", line 425, in <module>
    main(arguments)
  File "infrastructure.py", line 374, in main
    key_pair_name=arguments['--keypair'])
  File "infrastructure.py", line 387, in create
    key_pair_name, key_pair_fingerprint, key_pair_pem = create_key_pair(key_pair_name, region)
  File "infrastructure.py", line 64, in create_key_pair
    if e.error_code != 'InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate':
AttributeError: 'exceptions.OSError' object has no attribute 'error_code'

Comment: @VinceB There is a seperate problem with your error handling code in that you need to use `e.errno` instead of `e.error_code` when determining what type of error occured.

Comment: @ppperry Thanks for pointing that out. I'm very new to python. This is my new error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "infrastructure.py", line 425, in <module>
    main(arguments)
  File "infrastructure.py", line 374, in main
    key_pair_name=arguments['--keypair'])
  File "infrastructure.py", line 387, in create
    key_pair_name, key_pair_fingerprint, key_pair_pem = create_key_pair(key_pair_name, region)
  File "infrastructure.py", line 65, in create_key_pair
    raise e
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @VinceB By the way, you should use `raise` instead of `raise e` when reraising a caught error, so that the traceback is preserved.

Comment: Is it possible the octothorpe in the string argument to check_output is being interpreted by a shell and is effectively commenting out private_key?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching over to a non-shell-interpreted set of arguments for `subprocess`. In the process, consider also explicitly specifying the full path to `ssh-keygen`:

```
public_key = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/ssh-keygen", "-y", "-f", private_key])
```

Comment: Thank you. I pasted a solution that I found. Yours also works.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my issue. There was an error on this line:

`public_key = subprocess.check_output("ssh-keygen -y -f #{}".format(private_key))`

I resolved it by doing the following:

`os.chmod(private_key, 0o400) 
command = "ssh-keygen -y -f {}".format(private_key) 
public_key = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', command])`

I still don't know exactly why this issue occurred but it works now.

Comment: The reason you're getting the error is because `subprocess` doesn't use a shell by default (unless `shell=True` is set as a keyword argument). Because of that, it has no way of (a) figuring out where ssh-keygen lives [because no PATH] and (b) no way of deciding how to parse the arguments out of your string [because shells normally do the argument parsing]. Hence why my version which passes a list of arguments instead of a string works, and why your version that invokes `bash` also works, for different reasons.